# no matching function for call to "ClassName::ClassName()"

Tags: c++, constructor, arduino

I'm using cpp on Arduino. Let's say I have my variable defined as

```
ClassName o;
```

I'm not sure exactly what is going on here but it appears like the object is being created on the spot, looking for a default constructor that has no parameters. I don't have such a default constructor, hence the error:

```
no matching function for call to "ClassName::ClassName()"
```

However if I add a pointer to the variable then all is well:

```
ClassName* o;
```

What is going on here? What is the recommended way to take advantage of each of these styles?

Comment: `ClassName* o;` does not call any constructor nor does it create an object. It merely declares a pointer that you may assign to point to an object, but unless you do so it points to some undefined memory location

Comment: `ClassName* o;` should be `std::unique_ptr<ClassName> o;` or `std::shared_ptr<ClassName> o;`. Don't use raw pointers please.

Comment: I wouldn't really call them different styles. They are different types with distinct purposes, usages and lifetime implications. Also, substituting a raw pointer for a variable of automatic storage duration is asking for pain.

Comment: "it appears like the object is being created on the spot, looking for a default constructor that has no parameters. I don't have such a default constructor, hence the error" -- Yes, that's exactly what's going on.

Comment: Asking this question with such a high reputation?

Comment: @AlBundy I will always be curious about all things technology. That means I have to "start over" with basics of new languages, I've done this a handful of times over the years). Typically I can find solutions in research but every now and again the scenario is complex enough against my limited terminology that it makes more sense to ask SOF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure exactly what is going on here but it appears like the object is being created on the spot, looking for a default constructor that has no parameters. I don't have such a default constructor, hence the error.

That is *exactly* what is going on here.  If you declare a variable like that, it is created immediately.  If the constructor needs arguments - just supply them in the declaration:

```
   Class o(arg);
```

If you haven't got the value of `arg` yet - just put off declaring the variable until you have.  If you really must put off the creating the object until much later, use:

```
    std::unique_ptr<Class> o;     // This declare a unique ptr and
                                  // initializes it to empty.

    ....
    o = make_unique<Class>(arg);  // Create the object on the heap,
                                  // and store the pointer in 'o'.
```

When `o` goes out of scope the object will be destroyed (deterministically).

For a beginner, just don't use raw pointers.  They are too easy to get wrong.

Comment: What decides that `o` will be "deterministically" destroyed after falling out of scope?

Comment: The language specification.  The compiler arranges that the destructor will be called if you: fall out of the block the variable is defined in, if you return from the function, or if you call an exception.  The specification says you can rely on the destructor being called, and exactly when it will be called (relative to other destructors).  This is unlike garbage collectors when you don't know when (if ever) an object will be finalized.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the class does not declare the default constructor. Perhaps it has only constructors with parameters.

You have to declare the default constructor if you are going to declare objects of the class like

```
ClassName o;
```

As for the pointer declaration then it declares just a pointer, neither object of the class is created.

Comment: Just like the question said